# How to use system.drawing in visual studio 2012 express?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, drawing

I am trying to do image manipulation in c# in windows 7 using VS 2012 express desktop. I made a console app with this code, and its giving errors about Bitmap cannot be found. Does anyone know whats wrong?

I already imported the system.drawing, but still cannot be found...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ImageSplit
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Drawing.Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height);
            Bitmap src = Image.FromFile(fileName) as Bitmap;
            Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

            using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
               g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the *exact* error message you're getting?

Comment: The type or namespace bitmap cannot be found. Are you missing an assembly reference..

Comment: Its for bitmap, and some other ones. They should all be from system drawing though...

Comment: Have you included the reference to the `System.Drawing` *assembly* (right-click the project, Add Reference)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include a reference to the `System.Drawing` *assembly* in the project. Referencing/importing the namespace is not enough for the linker to find the assembly in question. This is what the error message is referring to by "Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Right-click the project, select "Add Reference..." and choose the appropriate file. This will add a reference to the assembly in the /References virtual project folder.